# generar una condicion y se ejecute dentro de un IF

Tags: sql-server

Buen día a todos, espero y alguien haya trabajado con mi requerimiento. Tengo un query el cual se ejecuta dentro de un SP, me gustaría que estuviera dentro de una condición(IF) y que si hay un error en la ejecución, me mandara un mensaje de adventencia por consola. Muchas gracias.

```
alter procedure sp_reporte_instalacion
(   
    ---variables para crear calendario 
    @fecha_inicio datetime, 
    @fecha_fin datetime,


    --variables para generar el reporte
    @fecha_ini_repor datetime,
    @fecha_fin_repor datetime

)
 as

declare @fecha_inicial datetime, 
         @fecha_final datetime, 
         @fecha_actual datetime
declare @total int
set @fecha_inicial = @fecha_inicio
set @fecha_final = @fecha_fin
set @fecha_actual = @fecha_inicial

create table #temp_calendar 
    (weekday varchar(10), 
     date int,
    month varchar(10),
    year int)
    while @fecha_actual <= @fecha_final
     begin
        insert into #temp_calendar
            select                 
                   datename(dw, @fecha_actual), 
                   datepart(day, @fecha_actual), 
                   datename(month, @fecha_actual),                     
                   datepart(year, @fecha_actual)                   
            set @fecha_actual = dateadd(dd, 1, @fecha_actual)                   
     end

;
----REPORTE
    Select  datepart(day,sh.[Order Date]) as Fecha,
            sh.[Responsibility Center],
           (select COUNT ([Unit of Measure Code]) 
            from [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Invoice Line]
            where [Document No_]=sih.[No_]
            and [Unit of Measure Code]='DIA'
            and (charindex('S-HANDS FREE',upper([No_]))<=0)
            and(charindex('GARAN',upper([No_]))<=0)
            and(charindex('DEMO',upper([No_]))<=0))Vendidas,

           (select COUNT ([Unit of Measure Code]) 
            from [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Line] 
                where     [Document No_]=sh.No_ and [Pre Service Start Date]<>'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000' and [Unit of Measure Code]='DIA')Instaladas

                into #temp_Temporal

     from [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Header] sh
                    inner join [Pointer Mexico SA$Customer] c on sh.[Sell-to Customer No_] =c.[No_]
                    inner join [Pointer Mexico SA$Sales Invoice Header] sih on sh.[No_]=[Order No_]                 

     where sih.[Order Date] between @fecha_ini_repor and @fecha_fin_repor and sh.[Shortcut Dimension 1 Code] in ('DV10','DV30') 
     --where sih.[Order Date] between @fecha_inicial and @fecha_final and sh.[Shortcut Dimension 1 Code] in ('DV10','DV30') 
      and  ((charindex('DEMO',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0) AND (charindex('RENO',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0) 
      and (charindex('CESI',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0)and      (charindex('GARAN',upper(sh.[External Document No_])) <= 0) )
      and sih.[Reason Code]<>'GARANTIAS' and sh.[Tipo de Venta]<>'ACCESORIOS'  
order by Fecha asc



;with Transp as (
        select Fecha        
               ,sum(Vendidas) as Total_Vendidas
               ,sum(Instaladas) as Total_Instaladas
               ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMEX' then sum(Vendidas) end as Vendidas_CMEX
               ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMTY' then sum(Vendidas) end as Vendidas_CMTY
               ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMEX' then sum(Instaladas) end as Instaladas_CMEX
               ,case when [Responsibility Center] = 'CMTY' then sum(Instaladas) end as Instaladas_CMTY
               from #temp_Temporal  right join #temp_calendar  on date = Fecha
            group by Fecha , [Responsibility Center] 
    ) select Fecha
    , sum(Vendidas_CMEX) Vendidas_CMEX, sum(Vendidas_CMTY) Vendidas_CMTY
    , sum(Instaladas_CMEX) Instaladas_CMEX , sum(Instaladas_CMTY) Instaladas_CMTY
    , Sum(Total_Vendidas) Total_Vendidas, sum(Total_Instaladas) Total_Instaladas
    From Transp
    group by Fecha 
    order by Fecha asc 

drop table #temp_calendar
drop table #temp_Temporal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IF statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms182717(v=sql.120).aspx)

Para la sentencia if haz esto:
IF condicional
Begin
..... tu codigo
End

[Raiserror](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178592.aspx)

Para la el error yo suelo usar raiserror que es la forma con la que se usan las excepciones, capturala en otro nivel o usar PRINT :)

Espero haberte ayudado compañero! :)

Comment: Muchas gracias.